# Java regex working differently on Android than in Java

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I'm using Java regex on Android and I'm seeing strange differences, as the following

Java: `"COSÌ".replaceAll( "\\W", "" ) ----> "COS"`

Android: `"COSÌ".replaceAll( "\\W", "" ) ----> "COSÌ"`

Anyone noticed similar differences between Java and Android String class?

Comment: Check your Java version too: android runs Java 6 or Java 7.

Comment: @TheLostMind: Android uses ICU regex, the last time I checked the documentation. ICU and Java are quite similar, but not the same.

Comment: @nhahtdh- Oh.. *The regular expression implementation used in Android is provided by ICU.The notation for the regular expressions is mostly a superset of those used in other Java language implementations. This means that existing applications will normally work as expected, but in rare cases Android may accept a regular expression that is not accepted by other implementations.* Well, this one mught be one of those rare cases :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Android

Straight from [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), right after the list of short-hand character classes (`\d`, `\w`, `\s`, etc.):

> Note that these built-in classes don't just cover the traditional ASCII range. For example, `\w` is equivalent to the character class `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}]`.

This would also explain why `Ì` is not replaced for the same code running on Android version.

While it is correct that the short-hand character classes also match Unicode character, the sample definition of `\w` Android documentation is **way** outdated. See Appendix for more details.

### Java SE

In contrast, in Java SE, by default, `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`.

`\w` only matches Unicode word character when [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) flag is specified. When the flag is specified:

- In Java 7, `\w` has the same definition as `[\p{IsAlphabetic}\p{M}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]`
- In Java 8, `\w` is updated to `[\p{IsAlphabetic}\p{M}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\u200c\u200d]`

### Workaround

Specify the character class directly. ICU regex doesn't support ASCII character class:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

---

## Appendix

#### Definition of `\w` in ICU

Here is the how the `\w` has evolved over time:

- The short-hand character class `\w` was defined as `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}]` (as shown in the documentation) up to [ICU 3.0](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/browser/icu/tags/release-3-0/source/i18n/regexst.cpp#L88).
- From [ICU 3.2](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/browser/icu/tags/release-3-2/source/i18n/regexst.cpp#L88) (released on 2006/02/24) and up to and including [ICU 4.8.1.1](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/browser/icu/tags/release-4-8-1-1/source/i18n/regexst.cpp#L75), `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}]` (equivalent to `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{M}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]` in the source code) is used instead. Changed at [revision 16634](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/changeset/16634/icu/trunk/source/i18n/regexst.cpp)
- From [ICU 49](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/browser/icu/tags/release-49-1-2/source/i18n/regexst.cpp#L75) (released on 2012/06/06), the current definition in the documentation is used `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\u200c\u200d]` (equivalent to `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{M}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\u200c\u200d]` in the source code). Changed at [revision 31278](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/changeset/31278/icu/trunk/source/i18n/regexst.cpp).

The string above is used to construct `URX_ISWORD_SET`, which is used in `regcmp.cpp` in `doBackslashW` to compile the regex.

#### ICU version used by Android

Even at [android-1.6_r1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu4c/+log/android-1.6_r1/i18n/regexst.cpp) (Donut), when `Pattern` class documentation is barren, it is already using ICU 3.8. [The source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu4c/+/android-1.6_r1/i18n/regexst.cpp) shows that it is using the definition from the second bullet point.

The documentation probably falls back to describe the behavior of the oldest version of Android.

#### Reference

If you want to navigate around the source code of Android yourself:

- `libcore` (Java Class Library)

  - From `android-1.6_r1` up to `android-2.2.3_r2.1`, [`platform/dalvik`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+refs) repository. `Pattern` class can be located at `libcore/regex/src/main/java/java/util/regex/Pattern.java`
  - From `android-2.3_r1` to now, [`platform/libcore`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+refs) repository. `Pattern` class can be located at `/luni/src/main/java/java/util/regex/Pattern.java`
- `icu4c` (ICU library for C)

  - From `android-1.6_r1` up to `android-4.4.4_r2.0.1`, [`platform/external/icu4c`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu4c/+refs) repository. Regex related stuffs can be found in `i18n`, Unicode related stuffs can be found in `common`.
  - From `android-5.0.0_r1` to now, [`platform/external/icu`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu/+refs). Enter `icu4c/source`, then similar path as above.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Android Regular expression syntax documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> Note that these built-in classes don't just cover the traditional
>   ASCII range. For example, \w is equivalent to the character class
>   `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}]`. For more details see [Unicode TR-18](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties),
>   and bear in mind that the set of characters in each class can vary
>   between Unicode releases. If you actually want to match only ASCII
>   characters, specify the explicit characters you want; if you mean 0-9
>   use `[0-9]` rather than `\d`, which would also include Gurmukhi digits and
>   so forth.

Thus, use a range to make sure you only match English letters `replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", "")`.

Comment: If you want to match Unicode case-insensitively in Java SE, `UNICODE_CASE` must be used with `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag; otherwise, only ASCII range characters are matched case insensitively. This has nothing to do with how character class `\w` behaves.

Comment: @nhahtdh: You downvote my answer because of explanation and provide the same solution? I would just comment without answering in such a case.

Comment: The solution is the same (it's extremely basic regex), but the explanation is completely different (before your edit), and I will downvote for providing a wrong explanation.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I really like your consistency that some of my downvoters usually lack. Thank you for healthy criticism.